# How can i read pipe delimited text using JCSV in java?

Tags: java, jcsv

In my project,we are using JCSV for reading comma separated values.We wanted to extend the support to read pipe delimited text as well.
The text is something like this:

```
NAME|AGE|Sex|Country|
Alpha|22|M|Switzerland|
Beta|23|F|Germany|
```

Comment: Why do you need a library? Just split the lines on a pipe...

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Does it work?

Comment: @cricket_007: For simple cases you don't need a library. But to support multiline fields and the separator character inside field values a simple split isn't enough.

Comment: Fair point. Anyways, Apache Commons is likely a better candidate. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html#Working_with_headers

Answer (score 0):

use append method of StringBuilder class and append | after each column of array